# Perl match ALL multiple words in string

Tags: regex, perl

I've string from a system  such as:
 "Mar 4 11:56:54 nxecopapp ftpd[20773]: [ID 44443 auth.error] unable to open module: stat (/usr/lib/security/pam_unix_session.so.1) failed: No such file or directory"

I need a perl regex that matches on **ftpd** and **auth.error** and **pam_unix_session.so.1** , ie all three

Comment: For your problem, does it have to be a regex, and does it have to be a single regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the order seems to be fixed, you need to compose a match like this:  match `ftpd` first, then any number of chars, possibly zero, then `auth.error`, then any number of chars, possibly zero, then `pam_unix_session.so.1`.

This directly converts into a regular expression.  The conversion procedure is left as an exercise to the reader.  :-)

Comment: if ( $TEST_STRING =~ m/(.+)ftpd(.+)auth(.+)error(.+)pam_unix_session\.so\.1(.+)/ ) { print "Matched\n" }else{ print "Not Match\n" }

Comment: You really don't need the first (.+) and the last one.  And you might or might not want (.*) instead of (.+), that depends on what you expect.  Otherwise, it looks fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
m/ftpd|auth\.error|pam_unix_sessions\.so\.1/
```

**Edit:**

Sorry, I read to hastily, above will match *or*, instead, you need this to match them all:

```
m/(?=.*ftpd)(?=.*auth\.error)(?=.*pam_unix_session\.so\.1).*/
```

Comment: Hhhmm , perl  doesn't like that.

Comment: Forgot the leading .* for the positive lookaheads. Though this is the general solution, I think you should consider Grrrr's solution, since it might be sufficient in your case, and is probably faster.

Comment: As said, the solution of Grrr is probably correct for AndyM, but he asked for something which would require lookaheads. The .* is indeed not needed, it's just to show where the rest of your regex (if applicable) should go.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*ftpd)(?=.*auth\.error)(?=.*pam_unix_session\.so\.1).*$
```

You can verify this online on [rubular](http://www.rubular.com/)

Comment: You don't need the trailing .* in the lookahead assertions though.

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my $s = 'Mar 4 11:56:54 nxecopapp ftpd[20773]: [ID 44443 auth.error] unable to open module: stat (/usr/lib/security/pam_unix_session.so.1) failed: No such file or directory';

if ($s =~ /ftpd .* auth\.error .* pam_unix_session\.so\.1/x) {
    print "match\n";
}
```

See: [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)